# dhcpcd.conf default netmask

Tags: networking, static-ip, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, dhcpcd

I wonder if anyone knows the behaviour of dhcpcd. I know that it is possible to configure wlan0 adapter to static IP in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` like that:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.1
```

Omitting the netmask in CIDR notation does not prevent dhcpcd from working. But does anyone know what netmask such configuration defaults to?

Comment: The default netmask for a class C (yes I know that's been replaced by CIDR) is /24.

Comment: https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd/issues/164

Comment: @Milliways how would you configure then adapter to a static IP? Why in your opinion it does not make sense?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#static-ip-addresses

Comment: @Milliways, I read your tutorials on setting a static IP address. Having this setting is useful for example when there is no DHCP server on the network... That can happen in a network on a ship, where there is no access to routers settings...

Comment: ... Raspberry Pi serves a page and I can access this page in a web browser using the static IP

Comment: You haven't described your setup. Do you have a router? Do you want internet access? Are you attempting to setup an access point?

Comment: I need to be flexible, Raspberry Pi acts as an AP. I still find having a static IP address a very valid option.

Comment: If you are setting up an Access Point netmask is meaningless. There are other essential steps to prevent dhcpcd attempting to use wpa_supplicant etc.

Comment: It is not meaningless if Access Point is configured to have a static IP addres. Imagine you have a basic network: Raspberry Pi configured as AP and a laptop with WiFi adapter. Now, let's assume Pi has the IP address 192.168.0.2 with netmask 255.255.255.0 (CIDR = 24). The laptop is configured to 192.168.0.5 with mask 255.255.255.0 At this point everything works fine. Now let assume I change laptops IP address to 192.168.1.5 with mask 255.255.0.0 In such configuration both cannot communicate (I double checked, it's in front of me on a desk). You have to change Pi's netmask to be equal or wider

Comment: ... for example 255.255.0.0 (CIDR = 16) Ergo the netmask is not meaningless. This is a counter example. I do not hookup the wpa_supplicant. There are extra steps like configuring and running hostapd. But all I described is beyond the scope of the question. Thanks for caring to reply anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a "Class C" address (192.168.0.1), if you don't specify a mask, it is assumed to be `/24` - iaw the old Class C definition. [More details can be found here.](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd/issues/164)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just wonder, is this default behaviour specified in some standard for a DHCP clients or is it a choice made for the dhcpcd implementation.

Comment: @maciek: I suppose it is based on the old "Class C" definition - a definition discarded for practical use many years ago. As you discovered in `ipv4.c`, RM made this assumption, but it could get one into trouble if the assumption were applied (for example) in a public IP space where the subnets can be much smaller than 254 addresses.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured it all out. :) But thanks.